# Reading text file, parsing it, and storing it into a hash. How?

Tags: ruby, file

I want to open a text file with three lines

3 televisions at 722.49

1 carton of eggs at 14.99

2 pairs of shoes at 34.85

**and turn it into this:**

```
hash = {
      "1"=>{:item=>"televisions", :price=>722.49, :quantity=>3},    
      "2"=>{:item=>"carton of eggs", :price=>14.99, :quantity=>1},
      "3"=>{:item=>"pair of shoes", :price=>34.85, :quantity=>2}
       }
```

I'm very stuck not sure how to go about doing this. Here's what I have so far:

```
f = File.open("order.txt", "r")
lines = f.readlines
h = {}
n = 1
while n < lines.size
lines.each do |line|
  h["#{n}"] = {:quantity => line[line =~ /^[0-9]/]}
  n+=1
end
end
```

Comment: Okay, so "what doesn't work"?

Comment: I have no idea how to iterate through and store each key,value pair into the hash

Comment: I figured a regex could capture the quantity but my iteration is breaking and isn't storing it as a value within the original key. The :item, :price, :quantity keys are nested and I'm not sure now to translate this into the code.

Comment: Well, then do something like this: `quantity = get_quantity_from_line(); price = get_price_from_line(); h[n] = {:quantity => quantity, :price => price}` (notice how it is really a bunch of separate actions). Now, to extract the value from the line, you probably want a single regular expression with *3 capture groups* - one for each value. So, start there - turn `"3 televisions at 722.49"` into "4", "televisions", "722.49" using a regular expression. Then it's just a matter of putting *that* back into the loop.

Comment: You can use one RegEx to capture multiple values? If it's returning more than one value how would I store each one individually? Wouldn't I need three separate RegEx's for each function?

Comment: You only need one regex with three captures per line :D

Comment: -1. Question is unclear. What is the rule for number on the noun? Why do "televisions" retain plural, "carton" retains singular, and "pairs" change from plural to singular?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No reason for anything this simple to look ugly!

```
h = {}
lines.each_with_index do |line, i|
  quantity, item, price = line.match(/^(\d+) (.*) at (\d+\.\d+)$/).captures
  h[i+1] = {quantity: quantity.to_i, item: item, price: price.to_f}
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
hash = File.readlines('/path/to/your/file.txt').each_with_index.with_object({}) do |(line, idx), h|
  /(?<quantity>\d+)\s(?<item>.*)\sat\s(?<price>\d+(:?\.\d+)$)/ =~ line
  h[(idx + 1).to_s] = {:item => item, :price => price.to_f, :quantity => quantity.to_i}
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
File.open("order.txt", "r") do |f|
  n,h = 0,{}
  f.each_line do |line|
    n += 1
    line =~ /(\d) (.*) at (\d*\.\d*)/
    h[n.to_s] = { :quantity => $1.to_i, :item => $2, :price => $3 }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know ruby so feel free to ignore my answer as I'm just making assumptions based on documentation, but I figured I'd provide a non-regex solution since it seems like overkill in a case like this.

I'd assume you can just use `line.split(" ")` and assign position `[0]` to quantity, position `[-1]` to price, and then assign item to `[1..-3].join(" ")`

Per the first ruby [console](http://tryruby.org/levels/1/challenges/0) I could find:

```
test = "3 telev­isions at 722.4­9"
foo = test.­split(" ")
hash = {1=>{:item=>foo[1..-3]­.join(" "),:q­uantity=>foo[0], :price=>foo[-1]}}

=> {1=>{:item=>"televisions", :quantity=>"3", :price=>"722.49"}}
```

Comment: In fact, you should use `split('at')` first.

Comment: I don't know why you'd want to split multiple times just to get rid of `at`; my original indexing figures didn't account for it and have been updated.